# Kendo Data form with Next/Prev record buttons

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to create a bound form with next/prev/first/last/delete/new buttons.

Is there any sample code or demos out there on how to implement this? Even better would be samples that also show a linked subgrid, a la invoice details/Line Items.

Thanks, Brad

Comment: Why can't you use the built in paging-->.Pageable(). As for the master-detail view, unless the grid is a client template or child grid, you will have to subscribe to the OnChange of the parent grid and issue an ajax call to fill the detail grid.

Comment: I need a form, not a grid for the master view.

Comment: Sounds like a good usage case for a partial view base form. One technique would be to place the actions in a base partial and have your edit forms inherit from that while dynamically loading their content. Your nav stuff could be in one place for most of the functionality - save, export, insert, delete etc.

Comment: I have not seen anything like this in kendo outside of the popup grid editor form.

Comment: @lrb. Looks like I will have to go native or bone up on Angular which is probably a good idea anyway.